# How can I identify row and column which has same value in matrix

Tags: matlab

In my research, I have to identify row and column which has same value in matrix.

here for example the form of matrix:

```
A= [60    27    45    72    22    14    56     2     8    39    18    12;
    72    27    60    45    11     7     3    23    41    17    56    39]
```

Then, I want to identify row 1 until 4 in column 1 and column 2.

here part of my code.

```
    done =all(ismember(A(1,1:4),A(2,1:4))); %Code that I want to ask you.
```

Please Look at in row 1-4 and column 1-4;

if I use above code, done will always give true (1). but it is not my desire, because `A(1,1)` is not same with `A(2,1)`, then `A(1,3)` is also not same with `A(2,3)`, `A(1,4)` is also not same with `A(2,4)`.

Comment: Can you clarify this a little? You question is unclear

Comment: Perhaps it is best you also include what matrix/vector/... you want to come out of this procedure.

Comment: If My updated post make you be more comfortable or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether the values in A(1,1:4) are the same as in A(2,1:4) you could just use

```
done =all(A(1,1:4) == A(2,1:4));
```